# The following classes could not be found! "Android-cardview"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

What causes the following error in the android.support.v7.widget.CardView in Android Studio?

Render errors
[I get this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxbwx.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add cardview dependency in your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

and then build your project.